# Copying lines when v is not implemented?

Tags: visual-mode, busybox-vi

Is there any way to copy / paste blocks of text when `v` is not implemented?`

Comment: What do you mean `not implemented`? Do you mean without entering visual mode?

Comment: I mean when you press the v key and it says it isn't implemented.

Comment: @leeand00 are marks available?

Comment: Well that's a strange error that I've never heard of before. Does it still say that when you launch vim with `vim -u NONE -i NONE`?

Comment: @muru it's complain about it, but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem it's vi

Comment: One other question, by copy/paste, do you mean yank/put, or are you wanting to access the system clipboard?

Comment: @Tumbler41 yank.

Comment: I'm working on OpenWRT.

Comment: Busybox vi is terrible. Install a better implementation if you can.

Answer (score 7):

I downloaded Busybox out of curiosity, and can reproduce
the problems you're having with that version of vi.
I have version `1.25.0-FRP-441-g53c3b08 2016-05-24 12:20:38 BST`.

A large number of vi commands seem to be unimplemented,
such as `:copy`, `v`, and `S`. `{` and `}` don't seem to work
properly.

In terms of yanking, the motions `}` and `/` don't work,
nor does jumping to marks, e.g. `y'a`.

`f` does work, e.g. `yfx`. More usefully you can use e.g. `2yy`
to yank a known number of lines. Even better, it looks
like you can set two marks with `m` and then yank between them with
with the ex command `:'a,'by` (yanking from a mark to the
cursor doesn't work).

Answer (score 4):

In case one uses number mode (enabled with `:set nu`) and both source and destination of the copy action are visible one can use a `ex` command:

```
:<line1>,<line2>t<dest_line>
```

e.g:

```
:5,9t17
```

copies lines 5-9 to line 17.

Answer (score 2):

Visual mode is not available in original vi. However, you should still be able to use a numbered yank or marks.

- In normal mode press `#y` to yank a block of code (where `#` is the number of lines you want to yank starting *after* the cursor's current line). Then you can just use `p` or `P` to paste it.
- In normal mode press `ma`. This will mark your current position in the file. Then move your cursor to the other end of the section of text you want to yank. Press `y'a`. This will yank everything between your cursor and the mark "a". Then you can use `p` or `P` just like before. Note: You can replace the "a" with any alphabetic character.

Se `:h y` and `:h m` for more information.

Comment: When I do that and try to paste it says 'nothing in register D'

Comment: That's quite weird. It seems put is trying to use register D for some reason. What happens if you do `""p`? (That's TWO double quotes and then a p.)

Answer (score 1):

I have installed vim package and got visual mode

`apk add vim`

Answer (score 0):

This is old question but I found this for the same reason as the OP (that I'm using openwrt), so I thought I would give the specific answer for that case.

The issue is that in OpenWRT by default vim is aliased to vi. You can check this by doing: `alias vim`.
That is set inside `/etc/shinit` (which is sourced at boot) and contains the following line:

```
[ -x /usr/bin/vim ] && alias vi=vim || alias vim=vi
```

This basically says if `/usr/bin/vim` is not present create the alias. The problem is if you install vim e.g. `opkg install vim-full`, the behaviour doesn't immediately revert and so `vi` is still launched when `vim` is run.

To fix this, you can run `unalias vim` or reboot (and the alias won't be created).

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se] and thanks for your contribution! Also note that you don't have to reboot, but just log out and back in to have the shell initialization executed again.